# How to bring the panel back

Tags: panel

I was trying to add shortcuts to the panel, and I accidentally deleted it. I am using Lubuntu 20.04, if that makes a difference. How do I bring it back? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried logging out, and logging back in?  (ie. causing your LXQt desktop to restart).